# Get names from multiple Facebook IDs

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the names and the url link to multiple Facebook ID's profiles whom I'm a friend of.

When trying to get one ID's info it's easy: `$response = $facebook->api("/123456789");`

I'd like to get the names from multiple IDs in the same request. Is this possible with FQL, and if so, how?

Comment: You can also query the API with `?ids=id1,id2,id3,…`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use FQL. You can easily query the Graph API with multiple ID separated by comma.

So it will look something like this in php:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . implode(',', $ids);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

Or if you are using the php-sdk like this:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/', 'get', array('ids' => $ids));
```

Where **$ids** is an array with the IDs of the profiles or pages.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible. the facebook sdk accepts a `batch` parameter with all requests in json format.
for detail information u may look here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/